# Как заставить React slick slider работать с иконками?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть такой код, которы выводит иконки

```
switch (name) {
            case Header.Arrows.name:
                return <ArrowsComponent key={name} color={color}/>;
            case Header.Zooml.name:
                return <ZoomTool key={name} color={color}/>;
            default:
                return null;
        }
```

Я хочу не просто выводить их, а делать это с помощью слайдера react slick slider. ArrowsComponent и ZoomTool это сами иконки. Как это правильно обернуть этот код в `<Slider>..</Slider>`

Answer (score 0):

Пример компонента SVG иконки:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

export const EyeIcon = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height={'1rem'} {...props} ref={ref} viewBox='0 0 1792 1792'>
      <desc>Просмотров</desc>

      <path d='m1664 960q-152-236-381-353 61 104 61 225 0 185-131.5 316.5t-316.5 131.5-316.5-131.5-131.5-316.5q0-121 61-225-229 117-381 353 133 205 333.5 326.5t434.5 121.5 434.5-121.5 333.5-326.5zm-720-384q0-20-14-34t-34-14q-125 0-214.5 89.5t-89.5 214.5q0 20 14 34t34 14 34-14 14-34q0-86 61-147t147-61q20 0 34-14t14-34zm848 384q0 34-20 69-140 230-376.5 368.5t-499.5 138.5-499.5-139-376.5-368q-20-35-20-69t20-69q140-229 376.5-368t499.5-139 499.5 139 376.5 368q20 35 20 69z' />
    </svg>
  )
})
```

В слайдер вставлять всё по [примеру](https://react-slick.neostack.com/):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Single Item</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <EyeIcon />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста зачем нам forwardRef в иконке

Comment: @AlinaHomyakova чтобы можно было стилизовать иконку если вы пользуетесь styled-components или другими похожими решениями